# css pseudo class

Tags: css, pseudo-class

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html> <head>
<title>How to Write a Good Report</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.weather strong:first-child {color:red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="weather">
It's <strong>very</strong> hot and <strong>incredibly</strong> humid.
</div>

</body> </html>
```

Why only "very" is in color red while "incredibly" not since both of them are first child of the element specified by "div.weather strong"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first-child` means "an element that is the first child", not "the first child of this element."

So your example means "the `strong` that is the first child of `div.weather`".

If you want to make, say, the first word in all the `<strong>`s within the div come out red, you'll need to add some markup and do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html> <head>
<title>How to Write a Good Report</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.weather strong span:first-child {color:red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="weather">
It's <strong><span>very</span> <span>very</span></strong> hot
and <strong><span>really</span> <span>incredibly</span></strong> humid.
</div>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: what if I want to select "the first child of this element."?

Comment: Is it selectable without add extra tags like span?

Comment: @Shore, do you mean 'is it possible to select all `strong` elements that are children of `.weather`?' If so, yes: `.weather strong` should select all `<strong>` elements contained within `.weather`. If you want to select only those that are children of only `.weather`, (not in any nested spans or whatever) then `.weather > strong` should work.

Comment: @Shore: It depends what it is you want to select.  You can't select the first word of the <strong> without wrapping it up in an HTML element like <span>.

Answer (score 6):

Because the psuedo-selector doesn't do what you think it does.

It selects, in your stated example, the first child of the element `.weather` that is a `<strong>` element.

So only the first instance matches. I can't back this up with reference to the spec, since I'm lazy right now (busy day...), but I have this sort of vision in my head:

```
<html>

<div class="weather">

<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum <strong>sit</strong> <em>amet</em> <span><a...>dolor</a><em>yadda yadda yadda</em></span> <a>something</a>, I'm not good at coming up with random text. Sorry...</p>

</html>

                                    Weather
                                       |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------+.....
|                |                     |               |                   |
(first-child)  (second-child)      (third-child)      (fourth-child)   (fifth-child)
strong         strong                em                span                a
                                                        |
                                                +-------+--------+
                                                |                |
                                            first-child     second-child
                                                a                em
```

It's not the prettiest ascii example, I know, but it's how I think of it.

Comment: Whether your answer is right or not (too lazy to read it...), the fact that you used an ascii art chart to describe your answer... you totally get a +1. Haha.

Comment: @Kyle, thanks, man...I've never had rep from, essentially, a `tl;dr` comment before =)

Answer (score 3):

I think you've meant

```
div.weather > strong {color:red;}
```

That will select children only (first level of nesting) rather than all descendants.

Answer (score 0):

div.weather strong:first-child says to select the first strong element that is a child of weather, not all of the child elements of weather. It's only going to match a single element ever.

div.weather strong matches all of the strong elements that are descendants of weather.
div.weather > strong matches all of the strong elements that are direct children of weather.
div.weather * strong matches all of the strong elements that are grandchildren or later of weahter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understand of "first-child" is wrong. The first child is the the first element only. See the [example at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Both `strong` elements are a child of the `div` but only the first one is the first `strong` child. So you just misunderstood the selector.